# build alljoyn_darwin in Xcode 6.1.1 and get a No SConstruct file found error

Tags: ios, xcode, build, scons, alljoyn

Recently I am doing some AllJoyn development on iOS and OS X. When I run xcodebuild for alljoyn_darwin.xcodeproj using command line as below:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project alljoyn_darwin.xcodeproj -scheme alljoyn_core_ios -sdk iphoneos -configuration Debug PLATFORM_NAME=iphoneos
```

I got an error like this:

```
export variant=normal
/opt/local/bin/scons -u OS=darwin CPU=arm BR=on BINDINGS=cpp SERVICES= WS=off VARIANT=Debug --

scons: *** No SConstruct file found.
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/scons-2.3.4/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 920, in _main
Command /opt/local/bin/scons failed with exit code 2

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    ExternalBuildToolExecution alljoyn_core_ios
(1 failure)
```

I really have no idea why I got this, I followed all the instruction in the official site--Build From Source and I am sure I set the correct OPENSSL_ROOT path. I installed scons using Macport and it was installed correctly. I tried double-click the alljoyn_darwin.xcodeproj from finder but I got the same error.

```
scons: *** No SConstruct file found.
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/scons-2.3.4/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 920, in _main
Command /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/scons-2.3.4 failed with exit code 2
```

So I am stuck here. But the thing is I can successfully run AllChatz sample in sdk_14.12 for iOS in iphonesimulator for iPhone6. openssl version is 1.0.2 and I tried build both for alljoyn sdks 14.06 and 14.12. same error happened. I don't know if this is related. Anyone can help here? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that scons cant find the root-level SConstruct script, which probably doesnt help much as you can see that in the error :)

When you use the "-u", that tells scons to look ***up*** the directory structure for the root-level SConstruct script.

SCons must be executed from ***within*** the project directory structure. Look for the root-level SConstruct, and make sure you're executing scons from within the project directory structure.

Comment: can you please add more description Your solution seems helpfull to me but I don't know how to execute from scons directory.
as xcode project is in alljoyn folder directory and shell script in xcdoeproj file.
@Brady